# Explorer causes 100% disk usage and computer to run very slow

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive

On windows 10 anniversary, Explorer seems to be causing the disk usage to go up to 100% and response times of higher than two seconds. I have confirmed it was explorer by killing the process, watching the disk usage drop down and restarting it and watching it go back to 100%. Is there any possible solutions to this, as using windows without explorer makes things complicated

Comment: open a cmd.exe as admin adn run this command **wpr.exe -satrt CPU -start DiskIO -start FileIO && timeout -1 && wpr.exe -stop C:\HighDiskFileIO.etl** and capture the high disk IO. If you captured it, zip the **HighDiskFileIO.etl** and share it (Onedrive share link). I'll analyze what your Explorer is doing

Comment: @mag https://1drv.ms/u/s!AgHU-eb9bMr9h0O4Y6gYFzcza9TY

Comment: @magicandre1981

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I checked the trace with [Windows Performance Analyzer](https://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Defrag-Tools/Defrag-Tools-44-WPT-DiskIO-Analysis) and here I see that most disk IO is caused by reading the file `C:\Users\blake\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Windows\Notifications\wpndatabase.db-wal`.

[image]

This is a  [Write-Ahead Log](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Write-ahead_logging) File which is created from [SQLite database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQLite) which Windows seams to use to store Notifications. Also your TOSHIBA MQ01ABD100 is a very slow HDD with its 5400rpm.

Disable as much notifications from apps as possible and look if this removes the disk IO.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to do this, unfortunately my HDD failed, which could have explained the disk response times

Comment: ok, failing HDD can also cause such slow performance. better buy a SSD now to solve any perf issuees related to disk. check the samsung 850 Evo

Answer (score -2):

I'd say it's quite likely a root kit malware that could cause such behavior (though I'm sure other things are possible as well to cause such a memory leak)

if rootkit, microsoft themselves suggest to use defender offline, as your existing antimalware probably won't detect it

http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/what-is-windows-defender-offline